# CakePHP 3 Dynamic Finders with underscores

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I would like to use a dynamic finder method. I've seen in [the documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#dynamic-finders) `$this->Users->findByUsername`. My problem is that my column name is `post_id`, and I'm not sure how the underscore affects the name of my dynamic finder function. Here are the ones I've tried so far and can't seem to get working

```
findByPost_id( $post_id )
findByPost_Id( $post_id )
findByPost_ID( $post_id )
findByPostId( $post_id )
```

For context here is what my code looks like

```
//VotesTable.php 
public function afterSaveCommit($event, $entity, $options) {
    if ( $entity->vote_type_id == self::favorite ) {
        $qt = TableRegistry::get('questions');
        $question = $qt->findByPostId($entity->post_id);
        $question->favorite_count = $question->favorite_count + 1;
        if ( ! $qt->save( $question ) ) {
            throw new \Exception("Unable to update favorite count", 500);
        }
    }
}
```

When I log `$question` it outputs a query, not an object, and the query can't be run. it ends with `WHERE 'questions'.'post_id' = :c0`

Comment: Post your whole code here. When I use dynamic loaders I use `findByPostId` and it works. It must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cake will convert the underscores to pascal case words, so you find it like this:

```
$this->findByPostId();
```

This is the correct way to do it.

Comment: I've tried using this method, and it's still not working. It returns a query and is checking for a post_id of `:c0` which doesn't make sense. I've tried hard coding in the value, same results.

Comment: I'm marking your answer as accepted, while overall my problem isn't resolved, my question is. I did a `$qt->find()->where(...)` and printed that result, and got the exact same output I was getting with what you gave me. Something must be wrong with calling the questions tables from `VotesTable.php`

Comment: When it says `:c0` in the query, you will see if you look at the debug of the query object it replaces the parameters with `:c0`, `:c1`, `:c2` etc. Those refer to another array in the query object, where the parameters get sanitised. To see if the parameter is correct, you need to see what the value of `:c0` is in the query object.

Answer (score -1):

If your column name is: **post_id**, you should use it as follows:

```
findByPost_id(2);
```

It seems that problem is somewhere else in the code. For example, if my column name is: **item_status**, I would use it like this:

```
// In the controller:
$table = $this->loadModel('ProcessItems');
$result = $table->findByItem_status(100);
```